# Conversion of string to integer, then again to string

Tags: java, android, string, integer

I am on a project developing an app on Android. Here I have to find a sum between two numbers defined as Strings and then display them on a textview. But my app is crashing. Below is my code. Is it optimal?

```
      String price=Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
            String fare=Cars.SUVFare[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
            String result="";
            int calc1=Integer.parseInt(price);
            int calc2=Integer.parseInt(fare);
            int calc3=calc1+calc2;
            result=Integer.toString(calc3);
            Price.setText(result);

        }
    });
```

spinner1:

```
public class Place_View {
public static final String[] locName = {"Sivasagar", "Jorhat", "Tinsukia", "Mohanbari", "Pasighat", "Digboi", "Majuli"};


public static final String[] prices = {"2625.00","3200.00","2000.00","500.00","4000.00","2800.00","4000.00"};
}
```

spinner 2:

```
public class Cars {
             public static final String[] SUV = {"Mahindra XUV", "Renault Duster", "Hyundai Creta", "Nissan Terrano", "Maruti Suzuki Brezza"};
                 public static final String[] SUVFare={"1000","800","800","750","650"};
}
```

Now I have to add the values of the strings prices and SUVFare when selected one of the both and put them on the TextView Price. Don't know how to post logcat so put the classes I made custom.

Comment: post the logcat also

Comment: Most likely the strings are not parsing as integers.  Logcat would confirm.

Comment: Please check my answer. - @Rinkumoni Khanikar

Comment: Possibly you are parsing a float number, with decimals so its not an Integer and therefore is crashing

Comment: @Ivan you are right I am an idiot 

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result=String.valueOf(calc3);
```

Instead of

```
result=Integer.toString(calc3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to convert an `int` to `String` in Android:

```
 int number = 78;
 String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     String price=Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    String fare=Cars.SUVFare[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    String result="";
    int calc1 = 0;
    int calc2 = 0;
    try {
         calc1 = Integer.parseInt(price);
         calc2 = Integer.parseInt(fare);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.e("Error","price or fare are not a Number in string format");
    }
    int calc3=calc1+calc2;
    result=String.valueOf(calc3);
    Price.setText(result);
```

Might be the String value you are extracting from spinners are not a number but a generic non numeric string which might be crashing while you parse using Integer.parseInt, just add a catch for NumberFormatException to avoid runtime crash.
and handle the exception according to your usecase by showing some message or whatever feels right for your app.

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

You're probably trying to do something like this:

```
String price = Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
String fare = Cars.SUVFare[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
String result="";
float calc1=Float.parseFloat(price);   //Note: float
int calc2=Integer.parseInt(fare);
float calc3=calc1+calc2;               //Note: float
result=Float.toString(calc3);          //Note: Float
Price.setText(result);
```

A full example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Price;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Price = findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLocation = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Place_View.locName);

        adapterLocation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapterLocation);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCar = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Cars.SUV);

        adapterCar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner2.setAdapter(adapterCar);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String price = Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                String fare = Cars.SUVFare[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                String result="";
                float calc1=Float.parseFloat(price);
                int calc2=Integer.parseInt(fare);
                float calc3=calc1+calc2;
                result=Float.toString(calc3);
                Price.setText(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String price = Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                String fare = Cars.SUVFare[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                String result="";
                float calc1=Float.parseFloat(price);
                int calc2=Integer.parseInt(fare);
                float calc3=calc1+calc2;
                result=Float.toString(calc3);
                Price.setText(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Old answer**

As Quick learner commented, we could be more helpful if you would post the error in your logcat.

I have a couple of questions about your code.

1. Are you sure you want to use:

   ```
   getSelectedItemPosition()
   ```

Because this gives you the position of the clicked item (0 for the first item, 1 for the second, etc.)

```
getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Above function will give you the value at the clicked position.

2. I do not completely understand what this line does

   ```
   String price=Place_View.prices[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
   ```

Are you referencing an array inside a view?

3. What is Price? And are you referencing it the right way?

Comment: Price is a textview,I am trying to display the result on it